# I'm trying to make 'Towers of Hanois' in Python, but my method of 'moving' items from list to list doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python-3.x

This is the (relevant) code that I'm using.

What it basically does is get the towers, then (hypothetically) moves the numbers to the correct towers.

```
        movefr = input("What tower do you want to move the last block from? " + str(nums) + " ")
        movef = int(movefr)

        moveto = input("What tower do you want to move the block from tower" + movefr + " to? " + str(nums) + " ")
        movet = str(moveto)

        #move numbers
        if movef == 1:
            if movet == 2:
                tower2.append(tower1[-1])
                tower1.remove(tower1[-1])
            elif movet == 3:
                tower3.append(tower1[-1])
                tower1.remove(tower1[-1])
        elif movef == 2:
            if movet == 1:
                tower1.append(tower2[-1])
                tower2.remove(tower2[-1])
            elif movet == 3:
                tower3.append(tower2[-1])
                tower2.remove(tower2[-1])
        elif movef == 3:
            if movet == 1:
                tower1.append(tower3[-1])
                tower3.remove(tower3[-1])
            elif movet == 2:
                tower2.append(tower3[-1])
                tower3.remove(tower3[-1])
```

It outputs something like this:

```
Tower1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
Tower2 = []
Tower3 = []
What tower do you want to move the last block from? [1] 1
What tower do you want to move the block from tower1 to? [2, 3] 2
Tower1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
Tower2 = []
Tower3 = []
```

Does anyone know hot to fix this? I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `movet` is String type:

```
movet = str(moveto)
```

Change this to:

```
movet = int(moveto)
```

Comment: Also using pop instead of remove would be much cleaner here